# Download and configure SDK in react native expo, third party payment gateway configuration

Tags: javascript, react-native, configuration, expo, payment-gateway

I'm beginner developing App in react native, I almost getting done 70% of my work using **react-native expo** but now I'm using **third party payment gateway** in it, but while installing I'm stuck in how to install **SDK** in my **react native EXPO**, first of all I don't have any **IOS** and Android folder in my project.. and that payment gateway kit have those folders too.
**I have No idea about how to install that payment gateway too**.

please refered below link for more information..
[Payment-gatway-github-link](https://docs.easebuzz.in/docs/payment-gateway/pq6k4fyf97c9p-react-native)

> if someone ask you to install above payment gateway in your react
> native expo app what you will do to get done?